# In a Group as a category C with one object, How is the bifunctor ⊗ : C × C → C defined on morphisms?

Tags: ct.category-theory, finite-groups

I know that for the one object {1,2,3}⊗{1,2,3} = {1,2,3}. But what is (1,2) ⊗ (2,3)?

hom(A⊗B,C) ≅ hom(A,hom(B,C)) so for A = B = C

hom(C⊗C,C) ≅ hom(C,hom(C,C)), so if the group is S3 = hom(C,C), then (1,2) ⊗ (2,3) is somehow not a permutation, but instead a morphism into the group itself?

If I write the permutations as permutation matrices, and the tensor product as the kronecker product of matrices, I end up with (2,3)⊗(1,2) being a 9x9 matrix which corresponds to (12)(48)(57)(69) but that sounds totally wrong.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be such a bifunctor? If there is a bifunctor as you write, the group is forced to be abelian.

Comment: Can a non-abelian group be a monoidal category?

Comment: Yes, if you instead take the objects to be group elements, and the underlying category to be discrete. David's comment is closely related to the Eckmann-Hilton argument: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eckmann-Hilton+argument